# My javascript running but the innerHTML just pop up for a second and then disappear again

Tags: javascript, html, flask, cs50

Please help! I try inserting into a div tag with innerHTML but I got stuck because the thing i want to insert just appear for a second and disappear again when the page is fully load.This is my Javascript:

```
var ra_rf = document.getElementById('ra1')[0];
var ra_beta = document.getElementById('ra2')[0];
var ra_rm = document.getElementById('ra3')[0];
var ra_ra;

document.getElementById('ra_submit').addEventListener('click', function handleClick(){
    ra_ra = ra_rf + ra_beta*(ra_rm - ra_rf);
    document.getElementById('ra_result').innerHTML = "DEMO" + ra_ra;
});
```

This is my HTML:

```
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="ra_submit">Calculate \(r\)<sub>a</sub></button>
</form>
    <div id="ra_result"></div>
    </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

I am using flask library:

```
@app.route('/ra')
def ra():
    return render_template("ra.html")
```

Comment: `document.getElementById()` returns a single element, not an array or a `NodeList`. I don't think you want the `[0]` on these calls.

Comment: thank you but it still not working. I think the problem is with the flask library in python but I can not figure it our since my javscript is seem to be working fine

Comment: JavaScript and your server are two separate worlds. The browser does not see or know about any of the details of Flask or Python. All the browser is aware of is the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript code that the server delivers. To illustrate this, imagine that your server were coded in Ruby instead of Python. Assuming that the Ruby code and Python code generate the exact same downloaded files, your JavaScript code would never notice the difference! What this means is that you can debug this entirely in the browser using the browser's developer tools.

Comment: It also means that you can create a standalone test case using only hard coded HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. You can even create this as a "snippet" directly inside your question. Or you can use JSFiddle or CodePen or any similar online tool. Creating a standalone test case that duplicates the problem would allow others to help troubleshoot it - or it may turn out that in the process of creating that test case you will discover what is wrong.

Comment: One other minor note: your `ra_ra` variable appears to be used only inside the `click` event listener. So instead of having the `var ra_ra;` _outside_ this event listener, you should declare it right there inside the listener: `var ra_ra = ra_rf + ...`. This won't be the cause of the problem, but it is something to fix just to be doing things the right way.

Comment: Thank you, I did make the change. Maybe I need to focus on what wrong with my javascript :)